# Ec2 Instance on stop and restart the instance cannot be accessed by that url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, webserver, aws-ec2-instance-connect

Recently I stopped my instance for 2 days and I again stated that the status is showing running. However, if I hit that IP in the browser it is not opening. It shows this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you assign a static IP to the instance?

Comment: yes i assigned a elastic IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using an Elastic IP Address. Go to the console and there should be a new public IP address.

If you're planning to use this instance more permanently you should take a look at adding an Elastic IP Address.

More documentation available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-allocating

Comment: After allocating elastic ip will that work.
Just now i associated an elastic ip to my instance

Comment: So you attached an elastic IP address, then tried to connect to that IP address in the browser (not the previous one)?